# How to know when a ListBoxItem comes into view?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Is there an event that tells me when a list box item comes into view?

The problem I have is that I can have several thousand elements that I set as my `ListBox.ItemSource`. Each element will generate a bitmap (which takes a while) so if I would just put this bitmap generation in the constructor creating the collection would take forever to create. Instead I want to defer the bitmap generation when an item comes into view.

Is there a way to do this? Ideally I would prefer not to loop through all the items and check if they are visible.

Comment: Your ListBox should have an ItemTemplate with an Image control. The Source property of that Image control should be bound to a property in your view model item class. Due to virtualization, the binding won't be initialized and access the source property before an item is actually about to become visible and hence a ListBoxItem container is created. The point is that the view model item does not create the bitmap before the property getter is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there an event that tells me when a list box item comes into view?

You could handle the `Loaded` event of the `ListBoxItem` container:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="OnItemLoaded" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

---

```
private void OnItemLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem lbi = sender as ListBoxItem;
    object dataItem = lbi.DataContext;
    //...
}
```

Comment: It fires only the first time when item comes into visible area.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`SelectedItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the initial selection and then you could generate your bitmaps for the few above and below it - the exact number will depend on the size of your bitmaps and the size of your `ListBox`.

I suggest you generate a slightly larger range than you can see so when you pan up/down your list you're not constantly waiting while you render the new bitmaps; think of Google maps - if you pan a short distance the image is already there and it's only when you pan a larger distance that you have to wait for it to redraw.

As you pan up/down your list you could use [`IsMouseOver`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ismouseover(v=vs.110).aspx) to find the item that you're currently hovering over and then update your rendered bitmaps accordingly, again slightly more than you can see.