# WPF: How to keep ListBox SelectedItem visible after resizing?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scroll, listbox

In our current `C#` `MVVM` project we use a `ListBox` to display items.

There is another container that can be expanded below the ListBox.

Everything is working fine. When the container expands, the `ListBox` contracts and the `ScrollBar` appears.

However if an element is selected at the bottom of the ListBox and the container  is expanded the item disappears at the end of the `ListBox`.

Example:

Before container expansion:

```
+--------------+
| Item 1       |
+--------------+
| Item 2       |
+--------------+
| Item 3       |
+--------------+
| Item 4       |
+--------------+
| SelectedItem |
+--------------+
| Item 6       |
+--------------+
| Item 7       |
+--------------+

+------------------+
| Container        |
+------------------+
```

After container expansion:

```
+--------------+---+
| Item 1       | S |
+--------------+ c |
| Item 2       | r |
+--------------+ o |
| Item 3       | l |
+--------------+ l |
| Item 4       |   |
+--------------+---+

+------------------+
|                  |
|                  |
| Container        |
|                  |
|                  |
+------------------+
```

What I would like to achieve is keeping visible `SelectedItem` without having to scroll to it.

Like so:

```
+--------------+---+
| Item 2       | S |
+--------------+ c |
| Item 3       | r |
+--------------+ o |
| Item 4       | l |
+--------------+ l |
| SelectedItem |   |
+--------------+---+

+------------------+
|                  |
|                  |
| Container        |
|                  |
|                  |
+------------------+
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

I couldn't find anything about it here on SO or anything else.

I have seen that it was possible to scroll programmatically:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a9116965-b1e9-411c-b153-b868e0a730cf/how-to-programmatically-scroll-a-scrollviewer?forum=wpf
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltohorizontaloffset?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Controls_ScrollViewer_ScrollToHorizontalOffset_System_Double_
- https://wpf.2000things.com/2013/08/21/889-scrolling-a-scrollviewer-from-code/

I have also seen it was possible to know when a `ListBoxItem` comes into view ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44963876/how-to-know-when-a-listboxitem-comes-into-view) and [there](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9efbbd24-9780-4381-90cc-a555d4782cd8/how-can-i-know-if-a-listbox-item-is-visible?forum=wpf)) but as my items are already loaded then hidden I don't think this will work.

I don't want to have code-behind that I must copy in every view where I need this functionnality. I have thought about implementing this in a Behavior attached to the `ListBox` but I highly doubt this would be the best solution.

I have also thought about writing a custom `ListBox` control but I think this is too much for such a small functionality.

Can someone tell me the best way to achieve this kind of behavior?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`Behavior`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/design-tools/expression-studio-4/ff726531(v=expression.40)) is the ideal way to add this functionality to a control. The code below will scroll the ListBox's SelectedItem into view after a selection changed or resize.

```
public class perListBoxHelper : Behavior<ListBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged;
        AssociatedObject.SizeChanged += AssociatedObject_SizeChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged;
        AssociatedObject.SizeChanged -= AssociatedObject_SizeChanged;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private static void AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollSelectionIntoView(sender as ListBox);
    }

    private static void AssociatedObject_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollSelectionIntoView(sender as ListBox);
    }

    private static void ScrollSelectionIntoView(ListBox listBox)
    { 
        if (listBox?.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        Action action = () =>
        {
            listBox.UpdateLayout();
            listBox.ScrollIntoView(listBox.SelectedItem);
        };

        listBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
<ListBox ... >
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <vhelp:perListBoxHelper />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ListBox>
```

More discussion about behaviors on my recent [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-behaviors-listbox/).

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed!
I just don't understand why you also listen to selectionChanged and had to remove this part because we allow multiple selection. But once again, thank you. I will give a good look at your blog!

Comment: SelectionChanged is what this behavior was originally designed to handle - when you select an item from code behind or through binding, it will be scrolled into view.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks! I don't need this part because it will not happen in my case but it might be useful someday. Thank you again

Comment: Maybe it would be better to make two distinct behaviors then - one for each event. You could then add whichever are appropriate for each specific Listbox instance.